# Capture multiple occurences after specific character with single regexp

Tags: regex

Lets say i have following path:

```
path = "/v4r/www/what3ver/te5t1ng"
```

I'd like to capture all occurences of \d after the last slash "/". So in this case i'd like to get ["5","1"]

How can i do it with single regexp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use look-ahead to assert there are only non-slash characters after the digit you are capturing:

```
\d(?=[^\/]*$)
```

Comment: I was thinking of look behinds to find the last slash... this seems a lot cleaner.  Nice one :)